# Include OpenCV to C++ project in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-studio

I've been setting up an Android Studio project that will use native OpenCV code, however when i try

```
 #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
```

i get an error saying the file could not be found. I've tried including the full directory instead but still no success.

The Android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on

include E:\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\OpenCV.mk
include $(OPENCV_MK_PATH)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := com_nicky_facedetection_OpenCvClass.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl
LOCAL_MODULE     := FaceDetection
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```

Ive added the c++ files i created to a Cmakelists file so that android studio recognizes them as part of the project, would i need to add the opencv.mk file too somehow? JavaCV works but ive decided to use C++ rather than Java if possible. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Do you have the NDK? I watched [this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JIHfqzTdOcQ) and managed to make opencv work.

Comment: @Vucko, ,my question was regarding opencv in C++. The java side of things works fine, thanks anyways! :)